# Where not working in LINQ operation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem where when I run the below, even if the call to OptionsMatch returns false (that method returns a bool) I still get the item in the resulting list finalItems

```
public List<SavedItemOption> GetValidOrderOptions(OptionsList itemOptions, List<SavedItemOption> savedItemOptions)
{
    List<SavedItemOption> finalItemOptions = savedItemOptions.Where(y => itemOptions.Any(x => OptionsMatch(x,y) && (y.actID == x.Id))).ToList();

    return finalItems;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would, potentially - because you're using `itemOptions.Any`. So if there's *any* x in `itemOptions` such that `OptionsMatch(x, y)` and `y.ActID == x.ID` then that `y` will be in the returned list.

Without knowing what `savedItemOptions` or `itemOptions` is, or indeed what `OptionsMatch` does, we can't really tell what's going on - but my guess is that either you don't want to call `Any`, or you *do* want to call `Any` but it's confusing you in debugging.

Comment: all I want is if the call to OptionsMatch returns a false, do not include that x in the ToList.  I thought the && would require both checks to be true..obviously this is not the case?

Comment: Bear in mind it's not including the *x* in the list at all - it's including the *y*. Big difference!

Comment: in either case, I'm fine with it.  Then end goal here is to compare 2 lists and only output those items that are in both lists.

Comment: I don't even know how this works in terms of do I have to first sort both lists for this Where clause to be able to see if one ID is in the other list?

Comment: You don't have to sort the lists, no - but there may well be better ways of doing this, depending on what OptionsMatch really does. If you can give more information, I can have a go at rewriting it...